# boot laptop from cloned hard drive attached to USB

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, external-hard-drive

I made a backup of a laptop hard drive (Lenovo ThinkPad E590) using AOMEIBackupper.  I've done this many times before, and I know that if I replace the laptop's internal drive with my clone, it will boot.

My question is, how can I boot off this drive when it's attached via USB in an external enclosure?  I try "boot from USB HDD" in the Windows Boot Manager and it doesn't work - it boots from the internal drive.  I'm much more familiar with legacy BIOS - put the drive at the top of the list you want to boot from and BAM, it boots from that drive.  UEFI is a bit of an enigma to me, along with the windows bcd tools.

FWIW, the external drive mounts as D:\ on the current windows installation.

I've read a lot of articles and tried a few things, but I don't want to make a mess and end up with an unbootable system - not that that wouldn't be fixable but I prefer to know what I'm doing before I start...

Answer (score 0):

Your USB hard drive should still be recognized in the BIOS menu and you'll be able to set priorities to load it first. Depending on your BIOS menu, you may have to dig into the boot options to find it. The "mounting as D:\" is what happens once you boot into Windows so that you can access the files so it's not relevant for booting. BIOS starts by checking what devices are connected and then showing/selecting a list of bootable devices, which your drive should be if the cloning went well.

Comment: Although this is true, windows itself will not boot. Just not gonna work. Any other OS, yes, Windows 10, nope.

Answer (score 0):

Windows installations really don't like it when you boot from an external drive. It will see your drive being a removable harddisk, and will simply refuse to boot from it. There is no way to get around this. Installing from a USB disk, yes, booting into a Windows installation that hasn't been modified, not going to work.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a feeling that this was the case or there would be more people doing it.  I didn't want to make a lot of changes to the boot files and render it completely unbootable - I can always swap it into the machine and boot from it.

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that the boot loader on the drive is telling the computer where to look for the operating system.  With a bit for bit copy of an internal SATA drive the drive in a USB enclosure is telling the computer that the next boot file will be something like SATA controller #1, third partition, named "BOOT".  The boot manager selection is likely working as it should, the problem is that the USB drive is then just directing the computer to a SATA drive for the next boot step.

The computer is just doing as it is told.  If you change this boot loader setting to point to the file "BOOT" inside the third partition of the drive on USB controller #2 then it will not boot once the drive is moved to a SATA controller.

There's ways to address this but some of them run the risk of leaving you with a drive that will not boot.

Perhaps if you disconnect the internal drive the boot loader will boot from the USB drive as it's not looking for a specific device but anything that has the right file in the right place, it's just finding the SATA drive first.  Maybe you can change the boot order in the firmware.

There's a lot of variables here making it difficult to give a definitive answer.

Comment: I'd really like a bit of a primer on modification of boot files.  I used to do this stuff decades ago when UNIX systems booted using hardware addresses stored in PROM, I'm used to typing complicated strings which could render a commercial server unbootable.  If I set my UEFI boot order to look at the USB drive first, then it's going to look for a boot loader on that drive. I fully understand how to get this to work with MBR, it's the sequence of commands to write out a UEFI boot record I need

Comment: it should not be rocket science to tell the boot loader to look for a local windows partition on the USB drive, I just can't find non-conflicting advice on the interweb on how to accomplish this task using the Windows BCD tools which often seem to be run with no arguements like which boot loader they are to act on.  What variables make it difficult to answer?  Thank you very much for your help, I really would like to learn this as it's bound to come up from time to time and it should certainly be possible to boot a system from USB - every single other OS can do it.

Comment: @DaveSpear  It looks like you are expecting me to come up with a fix but I can't help you.  I have training in electrical/computer/software engineering, computer security, and Cisco network devices.  My personal computers are Mac and Linux.  I know enough to have a very good idea on the problem but I'm not the Windows help desk type.  If I were given enough time with your computer I could likely figure it out but I can't do that from here.  I answered hoping I'd lead you on a path on where to look and/or give someone else a step in the right direction to take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was just hoping somebody could shed some light on the syntax of required commands. My background is Unix and linux so Max is very logical to me. Windows not so much. They make things needlessly difficult by gearing all their tools for one particular installation model and making it very tedious and difficult to make other scenarios work. Boot a live Windows install from USB?  Crazy talk, nobody would ever want to do that. We’ll restrict our boot tools to working on SATA channel 0 or 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Each laptop/PC needs to be setup for external boot via USB.  Here is an example on how to boot Dell Lattitude 7300 with all firmware tweaks..
##################################

1. Turn on (or restart) your computer, and press  immediately
   When the DELL Logo appears, hit the F2 key a few times to be sure.
2. After the BIOS setting is displayed, expand [System Configuration] under setting on the left side of the screen.
3. Select [USB Configuration] under [System Configuration].
4. Please make sure [Enable USB Boot Support] and [Enable External USB Ports] are checked.

   - If both are checked, uncheck them and check them again, then click 【Apply】 below.
5. Back to [settings], and next expand [Secure Boot]
6. Select [Secure boot enable] and make sure it is unchecked

   - If It is unchecked, check it and uncheck it again, then click 【Apply】 below.
7. Back to [settings], and next expand [General]
8. Select [Advanced Boot Options] and make sure it is checked

   - If It is checked, uncheck it and check it again, then click 【Apply】 below.

---

Internal drive is M.2 NVME... External drive is classic HD connected via USB3.0 enclosure. I used free Macrium Reflect- free version to copy drives and did not have to change/edit anything on the copied drive.